# PowerBI Embedded Capture Bookmark

Tags: powerbi-embedded

What is the purpose of the capture bookmark state function?  Is it to update an existing bookmark, which is what I am looking for, or save a new one?  I need to update a slicer and update a bookmark so that when they click the button again it doesn't lose the slicer value. Is this what capture is supposed to do?  The documentation is so bare for most functions it is not really clear of their purpose.

Thank you.

Comment: For example you can capture a bookmark and pass the captured state to the export to file API to export the report as is to a PDF file for example.

Comment: I have passed in slicer values and need to update a bookmark.  The documentation is so bare that it does not explain what capture means. It sounds like it saves a bookmark. If it saves it I need to reference it somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of capture bookmark state function is to capture the current state of the embedded report.

It provides a base64-serialization string which represents the current state of the report.

Currently, you cannot update a bookmark, but you can save the current state and use it whenever you want to switch to the saved state (like the bookmark functionality).

To update a slicer and ensure that the state is not lost, you can store the state returned by bookmark manager's capture function in a variable, and then use applyState function to update state of the embedded report to the state which was captured using capture function.

Please refer below snippet to see how to capture the state and apply it:

```js
// Create the filter object
const filter = {
    $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#advanced",
    target: {
        table: "Date",
        column: "Date"
    },
    filterType: models.FilterType.Advanced,
    logicalOperator: "And",
    conditions: [
        {
            operator: "GreaterThanOrEqual",
            value: "2014-10-12T21:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            operator: "LessThan",
            value: "2014-11-28T22:00:00.000Z"
        }
    ]
};

const pages = await report.getPages();

// Retrieve the active page.
let page = pages.filter(function (page) {
    return page.isActive;
})[0];

const visuals = await page.getVisuals();

// Retrieve the target visual.
let slicer = visuals.filter(function (visual) {
    return visual.type === "slicer" && visual.name === "4d55baaa5eddde4cdf90";
})[0];

// Set the slicer state which contains the slicer filters
await slicer.setSlicerState({ filters: [filter] });
console.log("Date slicer was set.");

// Capture the current bookmark and prints the bookmark's state string to Log window
const capturedBookmark = await report.bookmarksManager.capture();

let log = "Captured bookmark state: " + capturedBookmark.state;
console.log(log);

// bookmarksManager.applyState will apply the bookmark which is represented by the given state string
await report.bookmarksManager.applyState(capturedBookmark.state);
console.log("Bookmark applied from given state.");
```

**Embedded report (before applying captured state):**
[image: Embedded report (before applying captured state)]

**Embedded report (after applying captured state):**
[image: Embedded report (after applying captured state)]

Please refer MS doc for further information on bookmarks:
[Enhance user experience with bookmarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/report-bookmarks#capture-and-get-a-current-view-as-a-bookmark-object)

Comment: all the examples of capture & apply state in the documentation, and your example here, do not address how to save that state as a new bookmark in the report so it is available later. is this not possible?